# Javascript - Lists all the whitepaces indexes using REGex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to list all the whitespace index into an array.

I try this:

```
<script>
    var waw  
    var text1="Saya cinta bahasa java"
    var waw= text1.search(/\s/g)
    alert(waw)
    </script>
```

Fail. It only show the first whitespace index. While what I need to do is to list all of them into an array variable like waw.

It should be:

```
waw[0]= 4
waw[1]= 10
waw[2]= 17
```

Comment: Not quite clear: is it JavaScript? What is the expected output? What output do you get? Do you want to also search for Unicode whitespace? Perhaps, all you need is `alert(JSON.stringify("Saya cinta bahasa java".match(/ /g)));` (`JSON.stringify` is just for demo purposes)?

Comment: try "/\s/g" as input to the search

Comment: @sara: yes thats correct. But it is only returning first whitespace index. While I need to list all whitespaces of the string: Saya cinta bahasa java.

Comment: @stribizhev yes. It is JavaScript. I need to list all whitespaces indexes, The output should be: soo[0]=4;soo[1]=10;soo[2]=17. Since there are only 3 whitespaces.

Comment: At any rate, `var soo[]=` must be `var soo =`.

Comment: @stribizhev: what is that meaning? Can I use RegEx for this type of question?

Comment: Aha, you just need to get the array of indices, right? Still, only regular spaces, ASCII whitespace, or all Unicode whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the array of indices of each whitespace character in a string, you just need to iterate through all the `\s` pattern matches in a string, obtain a match and check the regex `lastIndex` property. No need to replace anything, or using a callback function.

```js
var waw = [];
re = /\s/g;
var text1="Saya cinta bahasa java";
while((m = re.exec(text1)) !== null) {
  waw.push(re.lastIndex - m.length);
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(waw)); // => [4,10,17]
```

Note that in JavaScript, `\s` only matches ASCIII whitespace.

Here is a list of ***Unicode whitespace*** (see [Unicode Character Categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)):

**Separator, Spaces `\p{Zs}`**:

> U+0020      SPACE
>   U+00A0      NO-BREAK SPACE
>   U+1680      OGHAM SPACE MARK
>   U+2000      EN QUAD
>   U+2001      EM QUAD
>   U+2002      EN SPACE
>   U+2003      EM SPACE
>   U+2004      THREE-PER-EM SPACE
>   U+2005      FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
>   U+2006      SIX-PER-EM SPACE
>   U+2007      FIGURE SPACE
>   U+2008      PUNCTUATION SPACE
>   U+2009      THIN SPACE
>   U+200A      HAIR SPACE
>   U+202F      NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
>   U+205F      MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
>   U+3000      IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE

**Separator, Line** `\p{Zl}`:

> U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR

**Separator, Paragraph** `\p{Zp}`:

> U+2029    PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR

So, you can get all whitespace with the following regex:

```
var re = /[\s\u00A0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000\u2028\u2029]/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the purpuse of this, but where's a way of doing it.

the replace method does not modify the original string, so just call it and pass a callback function, it will be called on every match, and you get as arguments the match, index, and capturing groups.

So I just pushed all indexes to an array.

```js
var text1 = "Saya cinta bahasa java"

var indexes = [];

text1.replace(/\s/g, function(m, i) {
  console.log(i);
  indexes.push(i);
});

document.body.innerHTML = indexes;
```